# Use LibGDX with Akka

Tags: scala, libgdx, akka

I'm experimenting using akka together with LibGDX and I have the following problem

```
ERROR] [09012017 174508.522] [WorldMap-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akkaWorldMapusergame] No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java124)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDepthMask(GL11.java1157)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGL20.glDepthMask(LwjglGL20.java256)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.begin(SpriteBatch.java170)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.draw(Stage.java127)
    at org.anacletogames.modes.WorldMapScreen.renderContent(WorldMapScreen.scala90)
    at org.anacletogames.modes.GameActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(GameActor.scala27)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala480)
    at org.anacletogames.modes.GameActor.aroundReceive(GameActor.scala13)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala525)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala494)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java107)
```

This happens as soon as I try to render something inside a Akka actor or trying to create a Screen inside the Actor.

Right now the actor could be summarized like this

```
class GameActor extends Actor with WithDelta
 {

   val fpsLogger = new FPSLogger
   var screenBaseScreen = null
   override def receive = {
    case CreateGame(s)= screen= s


    case Render =

      updateDelta()
      if(isTimeToRender) {
        ---game logic and stuff ---
        stage.draw()
      }
  }

}
```

When I call `.draw()` it breaks and this makes a lot of sense this is a different thread. Nothing changes if I create the screen inside the actor, it just breaks at the Screen creation. Now, while this behaviour feels logical, what can I do to circumvent this limitation of LibGDX Is there a way to achieve this I have no problem keeping a big Game actor but I need to divide the Game loop from the actor to achieve some behaviours I would like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you work with the UI, it is expected that you do interactions with the UI elements from a single thread, which would contain the main event loop. This is needed for many purposes; for example, lots of GUI libraries rely on some global state which is unsafe to access from multiple threads simultaneously. OpenGL is similar in this regard.

Most of the GUI libraries provide a way to run a piece of code in the main GUI thread. Swing, for example, has [`Swing.invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) function, and JavaFX provides [`Platform.runLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-). In case of OpenGL-based frameworks it is very likely that they are too low-level to provide you such a method; you probably have to drive the event loop yourself. In such case you also have to ensure that graphics-related code runs on the main thread manually.

The event loop usually looks like this:

```
while (true) {
  for (event <- pollEvents()) {
    dispatch(event)
  }
  draw()
  ensureFps(60)  // ensures that no more than 60 iterations are executed per second
}
```

Here the `dispatch()` function analyzes each event, which can be user input, some timer or whatever else, and modifies the state of the application, while `draw()` displays the updated state. It is important that this loop always run in the main thread, where the GUI library was initialized. This may be tricky if you want to put this loop into an actor.

It should work if you ensure that the actor always run on one single thread. To do this, you have to configure a [dispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html) which assigns a single thread to your actor. Then you have to do *all* initialization of your GUI library inside the actor or, at least, using the [`execute()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.html#execute(runnable:Runnable):Unit) method on the dispatcher (in the latter case you have to ensure that the executor contains only one thread). And then you have to make sure that you always work with your library GUI objects inside this main actor. Then there should be no problems with threading.